# Number of ACLs + output cache

Tags: output-cache

Does SharePoint 2010 have the same functionality as MOSS where output cache is bypassed if the ACL amount in a site collection is above 10000?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's the same hardcoded limit.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, I saw that when digging into SharePoint API using reflection. It will also be by-passed if the response as ANY cookie in the header (but that one is also the case for asp.net output caching).